# How can I prevent an account being moved that has an open opportunity

Tags: validation

An account with an open opportunity cannot be moved to another account owner

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. Best practice is to demonstrate some research to get the most from the community

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

- Roll-up on Account that counts the number of open Opportunity records under it.
- Validation rule using `ISCHANGED(OwnerId)` and the newly created roll-up field being strictly greater than zero to block the edit.

Consider including an exception to exempt certain users, such as admins, from the validation rule. A common approach that is permission set-friendly is to create a custom permission, wrap it in a permission set and assign it to the users that should be exempted. Then we would augment the logic of the validation rule by adding the following:

```
&& NOT( $Permission.NameOfTheCustomPermission )
```